# How to get samples from a RTP packet carrying PCMU?

Tags: c++, rtp

I have a pointer in a C++ code to a RTP packet (char* packet) carrying PCMU. How do I extract the samples so that I can dump to a file to play it? I've been able to extract the sequence number correctly, but how do I extract the samples to play them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to unpack data. The problem was related to the way I was reading the bits of the packets. Reading the CC and removing the header is sufficient to get the payload. According to the documentation it may be necessary to remove the padding as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of, you should try to use live555, which is a rtsp library with a lot of features that you can use to accomplish your work without lost time.

Second, you should read:

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3550.html

Where you can find some info about the protocol.

Comment: I'm working under Android, so porting a library may be long. I'm already reading the RFC, but still I'm experiencing troubles. I removed the fixed part of the header, but how can I remove get the CC to remove the CSRC and to remove the padding? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I see that you was able to accomplish this with the RFC! Good luck!

Comment: Problem was related to how the bytes are stored. MSB first, but my hex editor was showing it differently. Thanks!

Comment: Arduino port of live555 here: https://github.com/pschatzmann/live555